# find command behaving abnormally on rhel7 host

Tags: command-line, find

find command seems to be behaving abnormally when used with -user option

```
find /var/tmp -type f -user `whoami` -name *
```

or

```
find /var/tmp -type f -user udunto -name *
```

when used , prints file from root user also , tried negating but no luck

```
/usr/bin/find: './systemd': Permission denied
/usr/bin/find: './pcp'    : Permission denied
```

Comment: how's that abnormal?

Comment: Remove the `-name *`, or at least change it to `-name '*'` if you do really intend to filter out files whose names are not made only of characters.

Comment: command is trying to access file from other user , though user has been listed

Comment: The `find` is trying to descend into directories where you don't have permission. If you don't want to see these errors you can redirect stderr or you can exclude the directories from your `find`.

Comment: My question is at first place if i have mentioned a user , why find is trying to access other user file